# Как задать значение в поле ввода через джаваскрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://www.avito.ru/mahachkala#login есть форма, в которую я через js ввожу данные

```
document.getElementsByName('login')[0].value = "xxx";
document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = "pass";
$('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
$('button[name="submit"]').focus().click()
```

Прохожу капчу - но на выходе мне говорят - что я не заполнил ни логин, ни пароль
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так там же react, который ориентируется не непосредственно на значения полей, а на значения своих переменных, связанных с этими полями. И он ничего не знает про то, что Вы насильно поменяли значение input'а.

Comment: @Yaant а как быть)?

Comment: Можно попробовать вызвать событие "change" для input'а после его изменения.

Comment: @Yaant а что это даст

Comment: Ну, это даст знать react'у, что значение изменилось.